# Artifact of mesh will not Edit out, appears in Object mode only

Tags: modeling

[image]

Ball mesh, artifact only in Object mode, need to Edit out

Comment: please share your file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Is the artifact hidden in _Edit Mode_? Go to _Edit Mode_ and press Alt+H to unhide everything. Mesh parts hidden in _Edit Mode_ are visible in _Object Mode_.